# Difficulty in writing data in csv file in distinctive columns

Tags: python, csv

[image]

I was trying to write out float type data in a .dat file in terms
of two different columns. However, when I am trying to extract the
same data in a different program but as COLUMN-wise I got to
understand that the data wasn't written in terms of distinct columns
at first sight. Could anyone suggest a way out?

Comment: Please show code and data as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: However, I don't quite understand what you think is the problem. What you have shown looks right to me.

Comment: So you essentially want to write x in one line and y in the next?

Comment: @Terra, Yes,  I want to  write x in one column and y in another.

Comment: What you did was writing them in columns... If you want to write them in rows, then just do wrt.writerow(x) and wrt.writerow(y)

Comment: @Terra, I need to write the data in distinct columns so that whenever I require to analise the data I can extract column wise.

Comment: @mkrieger1 say I want to extract one of the columns I have written in some other program, how shall I proceed ?

Comment: @mkrieger1, f1= np.loadtxt("data1.dat", unpack=True) ; x = f1[0,:], but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

pandas might be a good way out.

download pandas
`pip install pandas` or `pip3 install pandas`

import it in your project
`import pandas as pd`

use it
`df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y})`
and then store it
`df.to_csv('name.csv')`

Comment: In that case, How can I extract say "x" column in a program ?